# How do I breed seagulls in Minecraft - Oceancraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-oceancraft

Seagulls are a new mob in Oceancraft. They are pesky to catch but can be bred.

I have managed to capture two in an aviary but I have no idea how to breed them. How do I breed seagulls?

Answer (score 1):

You can breed seagulls by using fish.

Source: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/suggestions/2371232-seagulls-edit-1-3-eggs-and-new-poll